# SOIL: saving a single channel image

Tags: opengl, soil

I am trying to save an image using:

```
SOIL_save_image("outimage.png", SOIL_SAVE_TYPE_BMP, width, height, channels, image);
```

'image' is an array of unsigned chars which I have loaded using SOIL_load_image. The loaded image is of a single channel. I am modifying the values of the image array before trying to save them back as a single channel output image. Even though I have passed the 'channels' parameter as 1, the output image is still a 3 channeled image. How do i save the output as a single channel image?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may also want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html), it seems that only 3 channel bmp files are possible:

> - Writeable Image Formats:
>
>   - TGA - Greyscale or RGB or RGBA, uncompressed
>   - BMP - RGB, uncompressed
>   - DDS - RGB as DXT1, or RGBA as DXT5

The only format that seems to support greyscale is TGA.